# How do i have my ppinter point to the new string i created

Tags: c, c-strings, strip, function-definition, isalpha

```
void strip_out(char *str) {


    int length_string = strlen(str);
    //printf("%d\n", length_string);
    char temp[length_string];
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
  while ((*(str + i) != '\0')) {

    if (isalpha(str[i])) {
            //printf("yes\n");
           *(temp + j) = *(str + i);
            i++;
            j++;
            }
        else {
            //printf("No\n");
            i++;
            }


     }
```

I need my `*str` value to be changed to the value of `temp` so i can use it in another function.

I cannot change the return type, if i could I could just return `temp` but it has to be `void`.

Comment: Why not *return* the "new" string?

Comment: Simplest thing would be to `strcpy` your `temp` to `str` in the end.

Comment: another alternative is to [`strcpy(str, temp)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strcpy.3.html) after the loop.

Comment: More common than `*(temp + j)` is `temp[j]`

Comment: You can do the transformation in-place. You just need to keep two indices to point where you are reading from and where you are writing to. Pretty much the same logic as you have currently.

Comment: a couple other things: 1) most agree that bracket notation `str[index]` is preferred over `*(str+index)` notation. You use both. 2) `i` is incremented unconditionally. You can drop the `else` and simply do `i++` after `if(isalpha...)`

Comment: btw, your `temp` is not null-terminated.

Comment: i cannot change the return type if i could I could just return temp but it has to be void

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change a string in place removing all non alpha characters then there is no need to define an auxiliary array.

The function can look the following way as it is shown in the demonstration program below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

char * strip_out( char *s )
{
    char *p = s;

    for ( char *q = s; *q != '\0'; ++q )
    {
        if ( isalpha( ( unsigned char )*q ) )
        {
            if ( p != q ) *p = *q;
            ++p;
        }
    }

    *p = '\0';

    return s;
}


int main(void) 
{
    char s[] = "1H2e3l4l5o";

    puts( s );

    puts( strip_out( s ) );
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
1H2e3l4l5o
Hello
```

If you want to create a new string based on the passed argument then the function can look the following way as it is shown in the next demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

char * strip_out( const char *s )
{
    size_t n = 0;

   for ( const char *q = s; *q != '\0'; ++q )
    {
        if ( isalpha( ( unsigned char ) *q ) ) ++n;
    }

    char *result = malloc( n + 1 );

    if ( result != NULL )
    {
        char *p = result;

        for ( const char *q = s; *q != '\0'; ++q )
        {
            if ( isalpha( ( unsigned char )*q ) )
            {
                *p++ = *q;
            }
        }

        *p = '\0';
    }

    return result;
}


int main(void) 
{
    const char *s = "1H2e3l4l5o";

    puts( s );
    
    char *p = strip_out( s );

    if ( p != NULL ) puts( p );

    free( p );
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is the same as shown above

```
1H2e3l4l5o
Hello
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering that you cannot change the return type, you could:

- add a final call to [`strcpy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcpy);
- fix the missing string null character (`'\0'`) issue. Without the terminal `strcpy` will keep processing data past the end of the `temp` character array until it happens to find a zero byte in memory.

```
void strip_out(char *str)
{
  char temp[strlen(str)];
  int j = 0;

  for (int i = 0; str[i]; ++i)
    if (isalpha(str[i]))
    {
      temp[j] = str[i];
      ++j;
    }
  temp[j] = '\0';

  strcpy(str, temp);
}
```

For a educational purpose the code intentionally is as similar as possible to the original one.

An *in place transformation* (the first part of [Vlad's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69544425/3235496)) should probably be preferred.